# VS code on my MAC after update to v.1.69.2 appearance problem

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, appearance

[image]I update my VS code on my MAC to v.1.69.2
when I open it I can't see the icons on the activity bar the icons are still hidden then when mouse over I can see also when I select my file code I can't see without put the mouse over it
any advice to return back my IDE work correctly

[image]

Comment: Sir, this is a̶ ̶W̶e̶n̶d̶y̶'̶s̶ StackOverflow. The VSCode support channel is here ~ https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is related to hardware acceleration. Try to disable it in the file `/Users/<your_username>/.vscode/argv.json` and uncomment the line `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true,`. Then, make sure you restart the IDE by quitting it first.

It would become the following:

```js
// This configuration file allows you to pass permanent command line arguments to VS Code.
// Only a subset of arguments is currently supported to reduce the likelihood of breaking
// the installation.
//
// PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE IMPACT
//
// NOTE: Changing this file requires a restart of VS Code.
{
    // Use software rendering instead of hardware accelerated rendering.
    // This can help in cases where you see rendering issues in VS Code.
    "disable-hardware-acceleration": true,

    // Enabled by default by VS Code to resolve color issues in the renderer
    // See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51791 for details
    "disable-color-correct-rendering": true,

    // Allows to disable crash reporting.
    // Should restart the app if the value is changed.
    "enable-crash-reporter": true,

    // Unique id used for correlating crash reports sent from this instance.
    // Do not edit this value.
    "crash-reporter-id": "81f0b16e-4c41-4fd3-b37c-b04c643b5f79"
}
```